# how to count the data using solr

Tags: solr

am using solr 6
    i am having 5 tables. i want to count the data for all table.
    i can fetch single table count. But i don't know how to get all table data count.

```
every table having different  core name
example user core name is user,user1 core name is user1

how to fetch the count for all table in single query ?

This is my code
$client = $this->solarium_client->solr(array("core"=>$this->config->item('school_table_core')));
$query = $client->createQuery($client::QUERY_SELECT);
$resultset = $client->execute($query);
echo $resultset->getNumFound(); 

return the correct count.
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no count method  for all talbe unless you have a solrcloud cluster,
so  you only can count every table and sum it , don't worry about , it is very fast .

Comment: Do you  know how to use multiple core  ?

Comment: it  likes database's mutiple table,  if you know one core how to use ,then mutile core also it